# Django Apache redirect static file issues

Tags: django, apache, django-admin

My site was setup with Apache and it does a redirect to serve Django.

`ProxyPass / http://localhost:15001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:15001/`

Now everything else works, except the static files. When I try to access the admin, the css / js dont load, and if I try the static files directly, I get this:

[image]

So, the redirect is making it think it's not defined in the URL's file.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Django serves static files automatically for the development environment (a.k.a. when `debug` is `True`). Other than that, you need to configure your web server to serve static files ([here is the relevant part of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-from-a-dedicated-server)).

For Apache, you need a line like this:

```
Alias /static/ /path/to/django/static/
```

Also, don't forget to make Django collect static files by

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: Did both, still does not work. There is a static dir, files are there. I have the alias line in apache. Uploaded images in admin are displayed, so that works, I have SOME static files but not the admin ones.

Comment: Here it is. Could not paste it here as I get an error it's too long: https://pastebin.com/PBJEnAAT